# Spyder: Permanently set an Anaconda environment as standard Python interpreter (with source & activate)

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I am working with Anaconda and Spyder which works well.

Lately, I have started to work with different environments which I create like this:

```
$ conda create -n my_env python=3.5

$ source activate my_env

$ conda install pyomo pandas numpy ipython

$ conda info --envs
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
# conda environments:
#
my_env                *  /home/user/.anaconda3/envs/my_env
root                     /home/user/.anaconda3
```

Per default Spyder seems to run the Python interpreter of Anacondas root environment.

Setting the default interpreter in the Spyder preferences (e.g. to `/home/user/.anaconda3/envs/my_env/bin/python` does not seem to be the same as activating environments and then running scripts.

So how can I permanently set (activate) interpreters of other Anaconda environments within Spyder?

BTW: I am on Xubuntu 16.04 X64 and `.bashrc` solutions are no option for me. I would like to solve the problem within Spyder.

Comment: Spyder itself is run under Python, so I'm not sure there's a solution that resides purely within Spyder's settings. On the other side, perhaps starting Spyder with `~/.anaconda3/envs/my_env/bin/python ~/.anaconda3/envs/my_env/Lib/site-packages/spyderlib Spyder.py` might work?

Comment: Have you tried launching spyder from the command line after setting the environment ?

Comment: I want to set it automatically. Meanwhile I went for the bashrc option!